# In a Svelte app, how to filter cities on a map with a double range slider?

Tags: filter, range, svelte

I have a Svelte app with a simple map of Scotland, along with cities plotted on top.
I want to use a double range slider to be able to filter which cities show up based on their population.
I've add the range slider, added an event handler, and the correct values are printing in the console log within that function. However, I want to then filter the data populating the map. I thought I could use an array filter method there, but it's not doing anything. I feel like this should be straightforward. Any help is very much appreciated.

My code is below. There's also a REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/2ad378c425694df2b334c6a6988b4fd5?version=3.58.0

**App.svelte:**

```
    <script>
      import { geoAlbers, geoPath, geoProjection } from "d3-geo";
      import { geoAlbersUk } from "d3-composite-projections";
      import { scaleLinear, scaleSqrt } from "d3-scale";
      import { extent } from "d3-array";
      import { onMount } from "svelte";
      import { feature } from "topojson";
      import { tweened } from "svelte/motion";
      import { interpolate } from "d3-interpolate";
      import Feature from "./Feature.svelte";
      import { cities } from "./cities";
      import RangeSlider from "svelte-range-slider-pips";

      let data = [];
      let colorScale = () => {};
      const width = "960";
      const height = "500";
      const projectionAlbers = geoAlbers()
        .rotate([4.4, 0.8])
        .center([0, 55.4])
        .parallels([50, 60])
        .scale(3800)
        .translate([width / 2, (1.8 * height) / 2]);

      const projectionAlbersUk = geoAlbersUk()
        .translate([width / 2, (1.85 * height) / 2])
        .scale(5200);

      const currentProj = tweened(projectionAlbers, {
        duration: 1000
      });

      $: path = geoPath().projection($currentProj);

      const opacity = tweened(0, {
        duration: 1000
      });

      onMount(async function() {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rveciana/27272a581e975835aaa321ddf816d726/raw/c40062a328843322208b8e98c2104dc8f6ad5301/uk-counties.json"
        );
        const json = await response.json();
        const topoData = feature(json, json.objects.UK);
        const land = {
          ...topoData,
          features: topoData.features.filter(
            d => d.properties.NAME_1 === "Scotland"
          )
        };

        const namesExtent = extent(land.features, d => d.properties.NAME_2.length);

        data = land.features;
      });

        let maxPopSize = 598830
        
      let newValues = []
      
      function handleOnChange(event){
        newValues = event.detail.values
        console.log('newValues', newValues)
        cities.filter((d) => d.population >= newValues[0] && d.population <= newValues[1]);
        return cities
      }

    </script>

    <style>
      svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 5em);
        background-color: "#eeeeee";
      }
      .borders {
        fill: #ddd;
      }
      .city {
        stroke: #777777;
      }
    </style>
          <div style="width:300px; margin:40px">
            <RangeSlider
            range
            values={[0, maxPopSize]}
            min={0}
            max={maxPopSize}
            pips
            pipstep={100000}
            float
            hover={false}
            on:change={handleOnChange}
        />
    </div>
    <svg width="960" height="500">
      <path
        class="borders"
        d={projectionAlbersUk.getCompositionBorders()}
        style="opacity: {$opacity}" />
      {#each data as feature}
        <Feature
          featurePath={path(feature)}
          initialColor=#ddd />
      {/each}

      {#each cities as city}
        <circle
          class="city"
          cx={$currentProj([city.lon, city.lat])[0]}
          cy={$currentProj([city.lon, city.lat])[1]}
          r=5
          fill=#000 />
      {/each}
    </svg>
```

**Feature.svelte:**

```
    <script>
      import { tweened } from "svelte/motion";
      import { interpolateLab } from "d3-interpolate";
      import { rgb } from "d3-color";
      export let featurePath;
      export let initialColor;

      const color = tweened(initialColor, {
        duration: 300,
        interpolate: interpolateLab
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      .provinceShape {
        stroke: #444444;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
      }
    </style>

    <path
      d={featurePath}
      class="provinceShape"
      fill={$color}
      on:mouseover={() => {
        color.set(rgb(initialColor).brighter(0.3));
      }}
      on:mouseout={() => {
        color.set(initialColor);
      }} />
```

**cities.js:**

```
    export const cities = [
      { name: "Perth", lat: 56.396999, lon: -3.437, population: 47180 },
      { name: "Glasgow", lat: 55.860916, lon: -4.251433, population: 598830 },
      { name: "Dundee", lat: 56.462002, lon: -2.9707, population: 148270 },
      { name: "Dundee", lat: 56.462002, lon: -2.9707, population: 148270 },
      { name: "Elgin", lat: 57.653484, lon: -3.335724, population: 23128 },
      { name: "Edinburgh", lat: 55.953251, lon: -3.188267, population: 482005 },
      { name: "Inverness", lat: 57.477772, lon: -4.224721, population: 46870 },
      { name: "Lerwick", lat: 60.154167, lon: -1.148611, population: 6958 }
    ];
```

I should note that the map code came from https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/rveciana/653784cfab5d859610926733cfb14773
(I removed the color and size scales)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output for your `.filter` is not assigned anywhere to be read by Svelte, you have to first declare another variable call `filteredCities`:

(Note that [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) doesn't modify the array in-place, it creates a new array and returned instead)

```js
import { cities } from './cities';
let filteredCities = cities;
```

After that, you can modify your `on:change` event to not return data (as it doesn't do anything for the filtered data), but rather assign to the `filteredCities` that we have declared just now:

```js
function handleOnChange(event) {
  newValues = event.detail.values;
  console.log('newValues', newValues);
  filteredCities = cities.filter(
    (d) => d.population >= newValues[0] && d.population <= newValues[1]
  );
}
```

Lastly, you can use this `filteredCities` instead of `cities` in your for-each loop:

```
{#each filteredCities as city}
<circle
    class="city"
    cx={$currentProj([city.lon, city.lat])[0]}
    cy={$currentProj([city.lon, city.lat])[1]}
    r=5
    fill=#000 />
{/each}
```